# Abstract class inheriting another abstract class with the same function name

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual, abstract

```
 class subscriber
 {
 public:
      virtual void update() = 0;
 }

 class entity : public subsriber
 {
 public:
      virtual void update() = 0;
 }

 class myObject : public entity
 {
 public:
      virtual void update()
       {
        do_things();
       }
 }

 subscriber * ptr = new myObject; //will use shared_ptr, but here i want simplicity

  ptr->update();
```

The question is, will the proper update function (the one implemented in myObject) be called? And is it valid to have 2 pure virtual functions with the same name in one "family"?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Surely just one abstract method would do the trick.

Comment: @Antonie Blom I have publish/subscribe pattern and every entity is a subscriber. There are 2 functions because there are updates called (using subscriber *) from object which stores published messages (if there any new) and there updates called from entity manager (using enity *).

Comment: What happened when you checked the behavior with your compiler? It should be easy to check this behavior on your compiler, No?

Comment: @Alok Save I don't have access to compiler right now, I'm on embedded device. I'm just designing now and check if it's valid.

Comment: @user1873947: [Now you do](http://ideone.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> will the proper update function (the one implemented in myObject) be called?

Yes, it will be called.

> is it valid to have 2 pure virtual functions with the same name in one "family"?

The second declaration (i.e. inside the `entity` class) does not introduce a second pure virtual function into the family: the signatures are identical, so `update()` is a single virtual function. Moreover, declaring it for the second time is not necessary: `entity` would remain abstract, and would have access to the `update()` method even if you removed the second declaration.

Comment: This answer was all good until the unnecessary *There will be only one vtable slot reserved for it, even though it appears in two places.* popped up? You don't need that to explain the OP that there is only a single function being overidden, do you?

Comment: @AlokSave I could go either way on it. To me, with vtable it's easier to visualize what happens with virtual functions, but I agree that it may not be the same for everybody.

Comment: Well moreover technically there may not be a vtable to begin with :) Hence my objection.

Comment: @AlokSave Yeah, I know: C++ standard does not talk about vitables for virtual functions, calls stack variables "variables with automatic storage duration", and so on, to avoid singling out specific implementations. Yet it seems that no matter where you look, there's invariably a stack for automatic variables and a vtable for virtual functions ;-)

Comment: Re *Moreover, declaring it for the second time is not necessary* -- It can be necessary if you are using a third party tool that doesn't fully understand the language. When I need to do that, I tend to prefix the declaration of `entity::update` as pure virtual with a comment such as `// #@$% SWIG`.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual function or virtual method is a function or method whose behavior can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same signature.

So the answer is *yes*.